# Monterey VM boot loop at trying to upgrade to Sonoma

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I need Xcode for a personal project and for that I need to upgrade my VM to macOS Sonoma. I tried it but idk why I get a boot loop. Any Answer?

INFORMATION:

VirtualBox Version: 7.0

VM OS: MacOS Monterey 12.0

Trying to upgrade to: macOS 14.0 Sonoma

Comment: Install a version of Xcode compatible with Monterey?  All versions are downloadable from Apple Developer.  You can install Xcode 13 or 14.

Comment: I could but I need Xcode 15

Comment: VirtualBox?  On what hardware?